# Dynamically set color of y-axis when x-axis has value in D3

Tags: d3.js

I'd like the y-axis label to be red if the x-axis value is 0. Not sure how to do this dynamically, image, code and JSON data below.

**JSON**

```
[ { yAxis: '15.1.4', xAxis: 3 },
  { yAxis: '15.1.1', xAxis: 2 },
  { yAxis: '15.1.2', xAxis: 2 },
  { yAxis: '15.1.3', xAxis: 1 },
  { yAxis: '15.1.6', xAxis: 1 },
  { yAxis: '15.1.5', xAxis: 0 },
  { yAxis: '15.1.7', xAxis: 0 },
  { yAxis: '15.1.8', xAxis: 0 } ]
```

**CS**

```
.axisRed text{ 
  fill: red;
}
```

**JS**

```
      svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
      data.forEach(function(d) {
      if (d.xAxis == 0) {
      console.log(d.yAxis);
      //??get the corresponding tick and then
      //- .attr("class", "axisRed");            
      }
      else {

      }
      });
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better idea is doing the other way around: looping the ticks with a D3 `each` method and getting the correspondent value in the data array. This can be done using the index but, for safety, I'l filter the data array according to the tick value.

In my demo, the data array has objects like this:

```
{title: "A",value: 23}
```

`title` being the categorical variable in the y axis (corresponding to your `yaxis`) and `value` being the quantitative variable in the x axis (corresponding to your `xaxis`).

Therefore, we can loop the y axis ticks and getting the correspondent `value`:

```
d3.selectAll(".yAxis .tick").each(function(d) {
    d3.select(this).select("text").style("fill", function() {
        var value = data.filter(function(e) {
            return e.title === d
        })[0].value;
        return value ? "gray" : "red";
    })
})
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var width = 500,
  height = 200;

var data = [{
  title: "A",
  value: 23
}, {
  title: "B",
  value: 0
}, {
  title: "C",
  value: 0
}, {
  title: "D",
  value: 24
}, {
  title: "E",
  value: 42
}, {
  title: "F",
  value: 59
}, {
  title: "G",
  value: 38
}];

var margin = {
  top: 0,
  right: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  left: 30
};

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([margin.left, width - margin.right]);

var yScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([margin.top, height - margin.bottom])
  .padding(0.2);

xScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.value
})]);
yScale.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.title
}));

var bars = svg.selectAll(".bars")
  .data(data);

bars.enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bars")
  .attr("x", xScale(0))
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.title)
  })
  .attr("width", 0)
  .attr("height", yScale.bandwidth())
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .delay(function(d, i) {
    return i * 200
  })
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return xScale(d.value) - margin.left;
  });

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
  .tickSizeOuter(0)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d;
  });

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ",0)")
  .attr("class", "yAxis")
  .call(yAxis);

d3.selectAll(".yAxis .tick").each(function(d) {
  d3.select(this).select("text").style("fill", function() {
    var value = data.filter(function(e) {
      return e.title === d
    })[0].value;
    return value ? "gray" : "red";
  })
})
```

```css
.bars {
  fill: teal;
}

.yAxis text {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```